# Swift Parse Push advanced targeting not sending

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Followed the [documentation for Parse advanced targeting](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-using-advanced-targeting) and push notifications are still not sending. (I can receive pushes from Parse's console and client push is enabled.)

```
let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "JrePAMWUbm") // The user I am logged in with

let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)

let push = PFPush()
push.setQuery(pushQuery)
push.setMessage("Hello, World!")

push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock {
  success, error in

  if success {
    println("The push succeeded.")
  } else {
    println("The push failed.")
  }
}
```

I keep getting "The push succeeded." But I look at Push Details, and it says "0 Pushes Sent."

[image: Push Details]

If I remove the userQuery and only use a PFInstallation query, I receive a notification.

```
let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
pushQuery.whereKey("deviceType", equalTo: "ios")

let push = PFPush()
push.setQuery(pushQuery)
push.setMessage("Hello, World!")

push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
```

Something is likely wrong with `userQuery`, but I'm not sure what. Return type isn't compatible with `pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)`?

Comment: what does your `Installation` object look like? specifically the `user` column that you are querying against?

Comment: @AaronSaunders Using the standard Parse `Installation` object. The `user` column is a relation of target class, `_User` (with column name `user`).

When I click on "View Relations," under the `user` column, it says "No data to display" though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything above is set up correctly.

My `Installation` `user` column was not associating with my users -- I had to add the following:

```
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
installation.saveInBackground()
```

This [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/user$20installation$20query/parse-developers/gLH2DRgNe90/nYjs0QiyhasJ) helped.