# The push is being sent to the database, but not to the user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to send a push notification to a user. I can currently send a push aimed at the user to parse, but it does not send it to the user. The user is registered in the installation class. Below is my code to send the push and the error on the parse website.

[image]

http://puu.sh/m0y7j/460b9f3ad8.png

[image]

```
 func pushNotifications(){


    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: Array(setOfSelectedFriends)) 

    let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
    pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)

    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    push.setMessage("Hello, World!")

    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock {
        success, error in

        if success {
            print("The push succeeded.")
        } else {
            print("The push failed.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not used Parse, but I can try to help. What error is return from `push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock`?

Comment: It says that the push succeeded.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218314/swift-parse-push-advanced-targeting-not-sending)?

Comment: Yes I have, I have put that code that in my app delegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I try to send a push from parse or from a device, the status is green, but there are no successful pushed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375501/when-i-try-to-send-a-push-from-parse-or-from-a-device-the-status-is-green-but)

Comment: Have you created all certificates needed to send push notifications ?